# When should I be compressing my Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, compression

I am creating one or more bitmap images from canvas, but I am unsure of where I should be compressing the bitmap images as I am frequently running out of memory.

```
    // create a bitmap from the canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(printOutBitmap, width, 0, null);

    // should printOutBitmap be compressed here?

    // Initialize a new ByteArrayStream
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Bitmap[] imgs = new Bitmap[numImages];
    Bitmap bitmapImage;

    // splitting the bitmaps
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < imgs.length; i++ )
    {
        // create a single bitmap from the area of the original bitmap 
        bitmapImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(printOutBitmap, 0, y, printOutBitmap.getWidth(), h);

        // the returned bitmap needs to be a predefined width/height
        bitmapImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmapImage, width, height, false);

        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        imgs[i] = bitmapImage;
    }
```

I compressed printOutBitmap but still ran out of memory, while compressing every bitmap takes too much time. Any help or 'best practices' would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compress()` saves a `Bitmap` to disk in a compressed format (PNG, JPEG, WebP). It does *not* change the memory usage of that `Bitmap`.

Get rid of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and the `compress()` call, as all you are doing is allocating a bunch of memory that you are not using.